# Telerik RadGrid Custom Header (Not a Group Header)

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I am developing a telerik radgrid on aspx. I simply want to add a row above the column headers, to show how columns are logically related. For example, 4 columns display data for 2014, and 4 columns for 2015.

I have the column headers, and the data, of course. I just need this additional info. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Once you begin customizing the header, you lose the ability to automatically build the table. You will have to customize main header, the subheaders, and the columns.

The [following page on Telerik's website](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-appearance-customize-gridtemplatecolumn.html) has an example of how to create a header template with a double row header. Below is the code example from that page.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
  <MasterTableView>
    <Columns>
      <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="ContactName" DataField="ContactName" UniqueName="ContactName">
      </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
      <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="TemplateColumn">
        <HeaderTemplate>
          <table id="Table1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="300" border="1">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <b>Address</b>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="50%">
                <b>City</b>
              </td>
              <td width="50%">
                <b>Postal code</b>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <table id="Table2" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="300" border="1">
            <tr>
              <td width="50%">
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem"City") %>
              </td>
              <td width="50%">
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem"PostalCode") %>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
  </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```